# Get city location from IP addresses inside a file

Tags: linux, shell, curl, cat, xargs

What a i need is to find the city associated with each IP address, I've stored them inside a file.

For example, the file's content is:

```
99.203.11.34
99.203.11.37
99.203.11.47
99.203.11.51
99.203.11.77
99.203.11.84
99.228.120.115
99.252.235.47
99.45.74.135
99.72.61.242
99.8.236.39
N ...
M ...
```

You can use the follow to get the expected results but one per one:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/<IP>/city
> city name
```

For instance:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/99.72.61.242/city
> Sunrise
```

---

I would like something like:

```
$ cat ip_list.txt | xargs curl ipinfo.io/$0/city
```

Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Where do you need the city info to be saved - into a new file?

Comment: @Ned64 Preferably in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `while read` loop:

```
while read -r ip; do curl --fail "ipinfo.io/${ip}/city" || break; done<ip_list.txt
```

This will read through the `ip_list.txt` file and set each line to the `ip` loop variable, then curl it.

Based on Stéphane's suggestion I have added the `--fail` flag to curl so it will fail silently upon a server error and the `|| break` so that it will break out of the loop.  ipinfo.io allows 50k API requests a month for free accounts so depending on how many IPs you have and how often you plan to use this that may be an issue for you.

Comment: You may want to make it `curl --fail ... || break`, to break out of the loop upon an error code returned by the server. ipinfo.io will rate-limit requests unless you pay a subscription.

Comment: @Jesse_b Excellent!   Just add a stdout redirecting .. so it will be something like:  `while read -r ip; do curl --fail "ipinfo.io/${ip}/city" || break; done<ip_list.txt > cities.txt`

Comment: @Juan-Kabbali ipinfo.io offers a limited amount of requests you can send to their API. I would use `geoiplookup` which basically does the same but is free!. As a side note: `awk '{system("geoiplookup " $1)}' ip_list.txt` would work for what you want

Answer (score 2):

For geographic IP address(es) lookup, I usually prefer using MaxMind's geoIP database. It is faster, as it does not an Internet connection for each IP address, as it uses a local database, and does not have limits on the number of calls.

If in Debian, as a pre-requisite, install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install geoip-bin geoip-database-extra
```

Then run the script:

```
 while read -r ip; do geoiplookup $ip | awk -F, ' /City/  { print $5 } ' \
 ; done < ip_list.txt > cities.txt
```